# jQuery .unload() doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>D</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
    </script>    
</head>

<body>
     <span>Hello world</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't show anything.

[Edit]
There are two things:

1. I had a dummy mistake, not ending with < / script> tag. Now, it's working on FF.
2. But not chrome, as genesis told, it's a bug!

Comment: Post the right code, the next time >_> Your previous code did not work, because jQuery is not loaded because of the missing `>`. Now, make sure that `jQuery.js` exists.

Comment: You need to close your `<script>` tag

Comment: @RobW, Thanks Rob. May be it's the bug genesis told. And thanks Eric!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `.unload()` event doesn't work in Google Chrome 14 and above. This is n[ew reported bug.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10509) (13 days old)

That is probably just a security measure from Google's side

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<script>window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'Your Returned String Goes Here';}/script>
```